# Create MediaPlayer in android studio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create MediaPlayer in android studio, but at the time of compilation it gives

```
"unfortunately project has stopped"
```

Code is as below:

```
MediaPlayer M = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    M = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.laugh);

}

public void play1(View view) {
        M.start();
}
```

Comment: share your error log

Comment: `          
05:05:32 م Genymotion: Starting device Sony Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920
05:05:33 م Genymotion: Device [Sony Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920]: started
05:07:00 م Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
05:07:34 م Gradle build finished in 33s 826ms
05:07:41 م Instant Run performed a clean build and install since
           the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.
 `

Comment: I have version 2.2 android studio;

Comment: This is not an error log. Run your application with debug mode and share the error log. Post it in your question not comment.